# Classification with partially labelled data - potential positives

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, classification

I am having trouble figuring out the best approach for a classification problem:

My data:

For each physician in my data, I have a feature set of every different medical procedure where the feature value is the number of times the individual physician performed that procedure.  The features have been transformed using a tf-idf weighting to account for procedure volume and commonality.  In addition, there is a single feature which marks the physicians specialty (ex: OB/GYN, cardiology, etc).

Classification problem:

There are sub-specialties among the specialties.  For example, you could be a Reproductive Endocrinology and Infertility (REI) specialist under your OB/GYN credentials.  There are certain procedures that are 100% predictive of the REI specialty (that is, only REI specialists will bill for them).  But not all REI specialists will perform for those particular procedures.  So what I have for my training is three classes:

1. OBGYN & potentially REI
2. OBGYN & definitely REI
3. Non-OBGYN.

I would like to develop a model which uses the "definitely REI" to predict which of the "potentially REI" are most likely to be REI's.  I'm struggling with how to appropriately train the classifier since it's very tough to label true negatives - OBGYN's who are not REI's.

Thoughts so far:

Train it using the labeled definite REI's as my postives, and my not-OBGYN as my negatives.  Then I would predict on my "OBGYN/potentially REI" set.  This seems like it would be a bad idea because the model will likely select for features that are unique to OBGYN's, not necessarily REI's.

I'm really only familiar with supervised learning, so if this is a well-established semi-supervised/unsupervised problem, I apologize.  Any insight would be a huge help!

Comment: Are there specialties besides REI that OBGYNs can have that you have in your dataset? And how many sub-specialties does a OBGYN typically have? (Really, what does the distribution look like--how many 0s, how many 1s, etc.)

Comment: Hi @MatthewGraves, thank you for the reply.  There are less than a dozen other sub-specialties they can have, but REI is the particular subspecialty that I am interested in identifying.  An OB-GYN typically only has one subspecialty (if any -- the majority of OBGYN's do not subspecialize).  As for the distribution, it's tough to say because I have over 8,000 features and since they have been tf-idf weighted, they do not typically take on integer values.

Answer (score 0):

How could this work, in principle? There may be some procedures that, while not always indicative of REI like the ones you've identified, are procedures that REIs do more (or less!) frequently than other OBGYNs. The ML model will pick up on those subtle differences, especially in combination, and come up with a classifier.

In a world where subspecialities are negatively correlated, you could train a multi-class classifier and use *both* positive and negative data--that is, if you know someone has subspecialty X, then that decreases the probability that they're an REI. But if subspecialties aren't particularly common, the value from this negative data will be relatively low. (One problem you'll also run into is that your model will be spending effort on differentiating the other classes that you don't necessarily care about.)

I don't think you're going to get much value out of comparing OBGYNs to non-OBGYNs, if your main goal is separating out REIs from other OBGYNs. (I'm assuming that you'll be provided with specialty whenever you'd want to actually use this model.) Especially if you're using a decision-tree based method, it'll likely just split out on specialty and then throw away all non-OBGYN data, which makes it seem wasteful to include it in the first place.

The two main contenders I see are comparing known REIs to possible REIs, and comparing known REIs to known Xs (where X is any sub-speciality other than REI). For *both* comparisons, you're going to want to exclude the procedures you used to determine subspecialty membership from the dataset, which should bring the subtler procedure differences to the fore.

Comment: Hi Matthew, what do you think about using only the OBGYN subset of the data and performing semisupervised clustering with two clusters.  I'd provide the REI physicians as the basis for the first cluster.

Comment: I think that'd work fine. Even though you have some REIs in the 'not definitely REI' group, you're comparing a 100% REI group to a <10% REI group; anything that's predictive of REI membership should still show up. (This is why it's important to exclude the things you used to separate them; otherwise the algorithm might just rediscover those and not do anything useful.)